# numbers going from int to varchar

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have column in a postgresql database. They are lottery numbers. Four digits in length to be exact. Initially I had the datatype of the column as int. I inserted all the lottery numbers. After I inserted all the numbers I realize it chopped off my zeros. For instance 0925 is 925. I fixed the datatype to be varchar but now I need to figure out how to fix it from int to varchar with the same data. The data needs to be 4 digits in length. I was trying to just figure out how many problem numbers there are and I couldn't write a select statement that told me how many rows have less than 4 digits.

How should I go about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was trying to just figure out how many problem numbers there are and I couldn't write a select statement that told me how many rows have less than 4 digits.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM lottery
WHERE char_length(x) < 4
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1fce8/1)

To fix them, you may find `lpad` useful. Note that the `WHERE` clause is not actually needed.

```
UPDATE lottery
SET x = lpad(x, 4, '0')
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/7d155/1)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simple to get the count with `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lottery WHERE x < 1000`?

Comment: @kgrittn: I'm working with the assumption "I fixed the datatype to be varchar".

Answer (score 1):

Format your numbers with [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_char(123, 'FM0000');
```

You might even just leave them as integer and use the expression in queries.

Or, to convert your column back from integer to text in place:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER column col TYPE text USING to_char(col, 'FM0000');
```

Since you seem to have already converted the numbers to `varchar`, the expression needs an additional cast to integer:

```
SELECT to_char(col::int, 'FM0000')
FROM   tbl;
```